# Background image disappear when I use CSS auto property

Tags: css

I have a span with a background where I want the image resized without loosing the radio. I mean not stretching. My image disappear when I use height: auto;

```
#logo_span{
  display: inline;
  background-image: url("../gfx/hs_logo.png");
  margin: -5px auto auto -100%; /* margin top right bottom left */
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: `background-size:contain;` is what you should be using. If you use `height:auto;` and there's nothing in that div to take up height, the height will be 0.

Comment: Just because an element has a background image, it doesn't mean that the background image has it's own height. You either need to use a fixed height or put something within the element with a height.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the height to an integer or percentage like so:

```
#logo_span{
  display: inline;
  background-image: url("../gfx/hs_logo.png");
  margin: -5px auto auto -100%; /* margin top right bottom left */
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 90%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

Another way would be to place an `<img>` inside this div but have another div with the same properties but instead of have an `img` have the `background-image`. However this is considered messy and can slow down loading speeds as your loading 2 of the same image.

```
<div class="hiddendiv">
  <img src="//file src">
  <div class="visiblediv"></div>
</div>

<style>
.hiddendiv img{height:200px; width:500px;}
.visiblediv {height:200px; width:500px; margin-top:-200px; background-image:url(//path to your image);}
</style>
```

This is just a rough example but this has worked for me in the past, no matter how much im not a fan of this method.

Comment: I want to keep the ratio. so I don't want to fix the height.

Comment: Then your best chance might be using my second option, i will edit the answer with the code

Answer (score 0):

If you want responsive image use `<img/>` tag instead css `background-image`. And then in css use `width: 90%; height: auto;`